# android:gravity - bottom vs. end. What's the difference?

Tags: android, layout-gravity

what is the difference between 'bottom' and 'end' constants of the android:gravity attribute?

I am aware of the official documentation here but I am not sure what the actual implications are:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#attr_android:gravity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"end" means "right" but with proper RTL support. So if your using an RTL language "end" means "left" ;)

See [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/huuJd8iVVXY) for more info